# Python Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make Conway's Game of Life where the user enters how big they want the grid and which cells start off as alive. Here's what I have:

```
def firstBoard(rows, cols, array):
    myList = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]
    for i in myList:
        i.append(-1)
        i.insert(0,-1)
    myList.insert(0,[-1]* (cols+2))
    myList.append([-1]* (cols+2))

    while True:
        rows = input("Enter the row or 'q': ")
        if rows == 'q':
            break
        cols = input("Enter the column: ")
        print()
        myList[int(rows)][int(cols)] = 1
    return myList

def nextGen(cols, rows, cur, nxt):
    for i in range(1,rows-1):
        for j in range(1,cols-1):
            nxt[i][j] = processNeighbours(i, j, cur)

def processNeighbours(x, y, array):
    nCount = 0
    for j in range(y-1,y+2):
        for i in range(x-1,x+2):
            if not(i == x and j == y):
                if array[i][j] != -1:
                    nCount += array[i][j]
    if array[x][y] == 1 and nCount < 2:
        return 0
    if array[x][y] == 1 and nCount > 3:
        return 0
    if array[x][y] == 0 and nCount == 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return array[x][y]

def printBoard(cols, rows, array):
    for i in range(rows+2):
        for j in range(cols+2):
            if array[i][j] == -1:
                print("#", end=" ")
            elif array[i][j] == 1:
                print(".", end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print()


def main():
    rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))
    cols = int(input("Please enter the number of columns: "))
    myList = []
    newList = []
    myList = firstBoard(rows, cols, myList)
    newList = myList

    print()

    generations = int(input("How many iterations should I run? "))+1
    for gens in range(generations):
        printBoard(cols, rows, myList)
        nextGen(cols, rows, myList, newList)
        myList, newList = newList, myList

main()
```

And if for the both the rows and columns I enter five and If I fill 3,4 4,4 5,4 i get this:

```
# # # # # # #
#           #  
#           #
#       .   #
#       .   #
#       .   #
# # # # # # #
# # # # # # #
#           #
#           #
#       .   #
#       .   #
#       .   #
# # # # # # #
# # # # # # #
#           #
#           #
#       .   #
#       .   #
#       .   #
# # # # # # #
# # # # # # #
#           #
#           #
#       .   #
#       .   #
#       .   #
# # # # # # #
```

when for the second and fourth boxes the dots should be horizontal instead of vertical. Please help i've been working on this all day and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your array initialization:

```
newList = myList
```

This isn't making a copy of `myList`, it's just making `newList` refer to `myList`, so then you only have one array. You can copy a 2D array like this:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

newList = deepcopy(myList)
```